# Replacing environment variable in index.html using Vite

Tags: reactjs, vite

I am trying to interpolate environment variables in the `index.html` of my React app using `vite`, however, I am getting the following error:

```
(!) %REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL% is not defined in env variables found in /index.html. Is the variable mistyped?
```

This is a sample of my configuration file:

```
/* eslint-disable import/extensions */
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'


export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), 'REACT_APP_')

  const processEnvValues = {
    'process.env': Object.entries(env).reduce(
      (prev, [key, val]) => ({
        ...prev,
        [key]: val
      }),
      {}
    )
  }

  return {
    define: processEnvValues,
    root: 'src',
    build: {
      // Relative to the root
      outDir: '../dist'
    },
    envPrefix: 'REACT_APP_',
    base: './',
    plugins: [
      react(),
      svgr(),
      tsconfigPaths({
        root: '../'
      }),
    ],
    publicDir: '../public'
  }
})
```

And this is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="refferer" content="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" />
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="%REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL%" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="ac-content">
      <noscript> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. </noscript>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script type="module" src="index.jsx"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am loading the `env` vars from `.env.development.local` and I can log them using `console.log({ processEnvValues })`

Comment: I've tested this in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ilfwcv?file=vite.config.ts) example and it worked for me